# Having trouble building single array from while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am trying to build an array from entries in a MySQL database.  I have connected to the database just fine, and I have a foreach loop which pulls the entries from the database based on the quantity of items like so:

```
$totalMarkers = count($results);

foreach($results as $result){
$gpsLats[] = $result->gpslat;
$gpsLongs[] = $result->gpslong;
}
```

I then need to take these entries and run them through a while loop to attempt to build my array:

```
    $it = 0;

while ($it < $totalMarkers) {
    $incr = $it++;
    $myLatitudes = $gpsLats[$incr];
$myLongitudes = $gpsLongs[$incr];

$items = array($myLatitudes,$myLongitudes);

  print_r($items);

}
```

The problem is that the output looks something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 54.8607 [1] => -32.4135 ) 
Array ( [0] => 39.8460 [1] => -87.4166 )
Array ( [0] => 78.8403 [1] => -95.4156 )
```

Really what I need is for all the entries to be contained in one array statement.  I have a good feeling that I am overcomplicating this, but I need a nudge in the right direction.  Thanks for your time in looking into this.

Comment: 1- `$items[] = array($myLatitudes,$myLongitudes);` 2- move `print_r($items);` to outside the while loop

Comment: Would it not be easier to build the `$items` array in your first `foreach` loop instead of running through everything twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the array 'append' operation:

```
$items[] = array($myLatitudes,$myLongitudes);
      ^^--- missing
```

Without the `[]`, you're simply creating a two-item array and overwriting it on every loop iteration.